# How to properly iterate across an array and work with scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm trying to take arrayOne and divide the indexes by the index number equivalent of arrayTwo. I wrote this very condensed mock up of my original code for readability.

Tried to re-write the code using different syntax but unable to do anything to fix it.

```js
let arrayOne = [ 2,7,5,89,4,67,8,5,3,8];
let arrayTwo = [ 5,87,5,3,7,89,5,34,7,98];
for( i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
    let arrayCombi = [arrayOne[i] / arrayTwo[i]];
    console.log(arrayCombi); 
    let topScore = 0;
    for( a = 0; a < arrayOne.length; a++){
        if (arrayCombi[a] > topScore){
            topScore = arrayCombi[a];
            console.log("Top Score; " + topScore);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, JS seems to be ignoring the If statement and will print out every arrayCombi index as topScore, rather than only update topScore when arrayCombi[a] is greater than topScore. I assume I'm using the iterator wrong.
If possible, it would be a lot easier if I were able to remove the created arrayCombi from the block code to be used later.

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: what is `arrayCombi` for. I mean what you expect it to be

Comment: Visual studio code usually does all that for me and I was having problems formatting the code for stackoverflow sorry.

arrayCombi (arrayCombination) is just the first index of arrayOne divided by the first index of arrayTwo, index two, index three... etc. It's to find out the cost efficiency of a product, I'm diving the performance of the product by the cost of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is topScore to be the maximum value of the array arrayCombi that is made of elements from arrayOne divided by arrayTwo. Then you need all these variables to be declared in the outer scope. You also ned two single loops, not the second nested in the first. And you need to use push(), otherwise you just reassign arrayCombi the new value [arrayOne[i] / arrayTwo[i]] (meaning it will always be an array with just one element). Try it this way:

```
let arrayOne = [ 2,7,5,89,4,67,8,5,3,8];
let arrayTwo = [ 5,87,5,3,7,89,5,34,7,98];
let arrayCombi = [];
for( let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++){
    arrayCombi.push(arrayOne[i] / arrayTwo[i]);
    console.log(arrayCombi);
} 
let topScore = 0;
for( let a = 0; a < arrayOne.length; a++){
    if (arrayCombi[a] > topScore){
        topScore = arrayCombi[a];
        console.log("Top Score; " + topScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it all with only one loop, by the way, just left both loops there in order to not change your original code too much